# For loop in SCSS with a combination of variables

Tags: html, css, sass

I've got a bunch of elements:
    (#cp1, #cp2, #cp3, #cp4)

that I want to add a background colour to using SCSS.

My code is:

```
$colour1: rgb(255,255,255); // white
$colour2: rgb(255,0,0); // red
$colour3: rgb(135,206,250); // sky blue
$colour4: rgb(255,255,0);   // yellow

@for $i from 1 through 4 {
    #cp#{i} {
        background-color: rgba($(colour#{i}), 0.6);

        &:hover {
            background-color: rgba($(colour#{i}), 1);
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 60):

Instead of generating the variables names using interpolation you can create a list and use the `nth` method to get the values. For the interpolation to work the syntax should be `#{$i}`, as mentioned by *hopper*.

```
$colour1: rgb(255,255,255); // white
$colour2: rgb(255,0,0); // red
$colour3: rgb(135,206,250); // sky blue
$colour4: rgb(255,255,0);   // yellow

$colors: $colour1, $colour2, $colour3, $colour4;

@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
    #cp#{$i} {
        background-color: rgba(nth($colors, $i), 0.6);

        &:hover {
            background-color: rgba(nth($colors, $i), 1);
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably be better to fetch the list length rather than hardcoding it: `@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {...`

Comment: For sure is better to not hardcode the length. I applied the change. Thanks steveax.

Comment: This response should be validated.

Answer (score 38):

As @hopper has said the main problem is that you haven't prefixed interpolated variables with a dollar sign so his answer should be marked as the correct, but I want to add a tip.

**Use `@each` rule instead of `@for` loop for this specific case**. The reasons:

- You don't need to know the length of the list
- You don't need to use `length()` function to calculate the length of the list
- You don't need to use nth() function
- `@each` rule is more semantic than `@for` directive

The code:

```
$colours: rgb(255,255,255), // white
          rgb(255,0,0),     // red
          rgb(135,206,250), // sky blue
          rgb(255,255,0);   // yellow

@each $colour in $colours {
    #cp#{$colour} {
        background-color: rgba($colour, 0.6);

        &:hover {
            background-color: rgba($colour, 1);
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer you can include each $colour in the @each directive instead of declare $colors variable:

```
$colour1: rgb(255,255,255); // white
$colour2: rgb(255,0,0);     // red
$colour3: rgb(135,206,250); // sky blue
$colour4: rgb(255,255,0);   // yellow

@each $colour in $colour1, $colour2, $colour3, $colour4 {
    #cp#{$colour} {
        background-color: rgba($colour, 0.6);

        &:hover {
            background-color: rgba($colour, 1);
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
}
```

[Sass Reference for `@each` directive](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive)

Answer (score 19):

SASS variables still need to be prefixed with a dollar sign inside interpolations, so every place you have `#{i}`, it should really be `#{$i}`. You can see other examples in the SASS reference on [interpolations](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_).